# How to Recover data using command prompt?

Tags: cmd

> I lost my folder and now i want to recover my data using command prompt. 
>   So, how can i recover my folder and which command is used ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using command prompt you can use the System Restore "rstrui.exe".
You could also follow this guide from Cnet to recover files from Recycle Bin using Command Prompt.

> To Recover Files in NTFS:
>
> Click Start, Run and enter %systemdrive%\Recycler. Under this folder
>   you'll see sub folders with names like:
>   S-1-5-21-1085031214-854245398-1060284298-1003
>
> One of these is your user's Recycle Bin folder, you'll have to
>   determine which. Then open a Command Prompt Window and type: Start/Run
>   and type in: CMD
>
> CD\Recycled\ Next type DIR
>
> Locate the files with the file extension that you wish to recover.
>   There may be more than one of the same type. These files will all be
>   DC??.xxx where ?? is a number and xxx is the file extension.
>
> Use the COPY command to copy all of the matching files out. For
>   example: COPY *.DOC C:\Temp
>
> to copy all DOC files to C:\Temp. Now you can open these files and
>   find the one(s) that you wanted to retrieve.

Guide: https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/recovering-permanently-deleted-files-help-226105/

Comment: Sorry but it's not worked for me i didn't got the Recycler in System Drive.

Comment: You could try some Third Party tools but honestly System Restore would be your best option as it will have the file and will not be corrupted or etc.

Comment: yea i am used Recuva,Easuse, and etc. But they also didn't worked because of Crack Version and i don't have license version.